# UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl not presenting viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to implement a UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl on a viewController to present a partial view of ViewController2 (I am using xCode 4.6 with storyBoards for a universal app). The following code does animate the UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl but shows only a black window underneath. So, it works (no crash) but it won't present/show the second view ??

```
   ViewController2 *v2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
   v2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
   [self presentViewController:v2 animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: If you're using a storyboard then you should use a segue for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized `v2` . you should use this :

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Your_storyboard_name" bundle:nil];

 ViewController2* v2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your_view_controller_identifier_from_storyboard"];
 v2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;

[self presentViewController:v2 animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Do any additional checks to see if it's iPad or iPhone and fill the information as is required.